# SQL Server column as alias in nodejs turn out to be empty

Tags: sql-server, node.js

I was trying to obtain queried column as alias:

```
var mssql = require("mssql");
sql = 'SELECT id, name, substring(json_metadata,5,15) as location_string, created FROM [dbo].[accounts] WHERE json_metadata like '%melbourne%' order by created desc';
getConnection.request().query(sql, function(err, result) 
    {
        callback(result);
    });
```

This SQL works well in SQL Server, however, with nodejs, the `location_string` always turns out to be empty.

Comment: Do you have a typo in your query?  (`substring` appears twice)

Comment: corrected now. it was a typo. thanks